# @here/maps-api-for-javascript has no exported member H

Tags: heremaps, here-maps-rest, heremap-navigation

I am following the Heremap tutorial present at https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.15/dev_guide/topics/angular-practices.html.

I copy pasted the code mentioned in it in my angular component. But the compiler complains that

@here/maps-api-for-javascript has no exported member H.

Anybody from Heremap developer community please help fix this.

Thanks,
Nealesh

Answer (score 1):

At Step 7 of [Here Maps Angular Doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.42.0/dev_guide/topics/angular-practices.html) :

> In the tsconfig.json file, add the following setting under angularCompilerOptions: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

And use this import `import H from '@here/maps-api-for-javascript';`

Best regards